Is "categorical geometry" a currently researched subject?
I've been studying differential geometry for a while now, and it seems like the whole "manifold" idea can really be generalised and as such, defined for objects of, say, arbitrary pairs of categories $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D})$ with $\mathcal{C}$ "being contained" in $\mathcal{D}$ such that "$\mathcal{D}$ is stable by intersections" which I will formalize below, instead of having to deal with the first category of the pair being the category of open subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ equipped with differentiable functions as morphisms (not necessarily diffeomorphisms to be clear,) and the second being the category of second-countable Hausdorff topological spaces equipped with continuous functions w.r.t. their induced topologies (may vary according to the definitions of a differential manifold.) I have tried to formalize what I call a "$(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D})$-categorical manifold" below :

Note : For more mathematical consistency, the following sets of objects or morphisms of categories discussed here will actually be $\frak{U}$-sets w.r.t. to a grothendieck universe $\frak{U}$ so we don't run into set-theoretical paradoxes, but that can reasonably be swept under the rug in the scope of this question in my opinion.
For two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{C}$ is said to be a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ if all objects and morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ are also of $\mathcal{D}$.
For a concrete category $\mathcal{D}$ over Set such that the forgetful functor $|−|$ of $\mathcal{D}$ from $\mathcal{D}$ to Set preserves pullbacks, let the relationship $\subset_{\mathcal{D}}$ (an inclusion enriched by $\mathcal{D}$ if you will) be such that for $X$, $Y$ two objects of $\mathcal{D}$, $X \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y$ if and only if there exists a monomorphism of $\mathcal{D}$ from $X$ to $Y$.
For a concrete category $\mathcal{D}$ over Set such that $|−|$ preserves pullbacks, $\mathcal{D}$ is said to be stable by intersection if for $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$ objects of $\mathcal{D}$ such that $Y_1 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} X$ and $Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} X$, then there exists an object of $\mathcal{D}$ noted $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2$ that verifies $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_1$ and $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_2$ and that is a pullback $Y_1 → X ← Y_2$ of the monomorphisms due to $Y_1 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} X$ and $Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} X$ w.r.t. the monomorphisms due to $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_1$ and $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_2$.
(Note that $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2$ is unique up to isomorphism since it is a pullback.)
For a concrete category $\mathcal{D}$ over Set such that $|−|$ preserves pullbacks and pushouts and is stable by intersection, for $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$ objects of $\mathcal{D}$, let $Y_1 \cup_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2$ denote a pushout $Y_1 ← Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 → Y_2$ (unique up to isomorphism) w.r.t. to the monomorphisms due to $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_1$ and $Y_1 \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} Y_2 \subset_{\mathcal{D}} Y_2$.
(In the case of pushouts, we don't necessarily want to always have them for every pair of objects of $\mathcal{D}$, so they do not necessarily exist.)
Let a geometric pair of categories ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) denote a pair of concrete categories over Set such that $\mathcal{C}$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$, $|−|_{\mathcal{C}}$ resp. $|−|_{\mathcal{D}}$ preserves pullbacks and pushouts of $\mathcal{C}$ resp. $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{D}$ is stable by intersection and the restriction of $|−|_{\mathcal{D}}$ to the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ is identical to $|−|_{\mathcal{C}}$. (To be clear, $|−|_{\mathcal{C}}$ resp. $|−|_{\mathcal{D}}$ are the forgetful functors of $\mathcal{C}$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to Set resp. $\mathcal{D}$ from $\mathcal{D}$ to Set)
For ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) a geometric pair of categories and $M$ an object of $\mathcal{D}$ :
$(i)$ Let $(U, \varphi)$ be a ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical parameterization of $M$ if $U$ is an object of $\mathcal{D}$ such that $U \subset_{\mathcal{D}} M$ and there exists an object $V$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism from $V$ to $U$ in $\mathcal{D}$.
$(ii)$ Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a (countable and indexed by some set $\Lambda$) ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical atlas of $M$ if the following conditions are met :
$(a)$ $\mathcal{A}$ is a (countable) set of ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical parameterizations of $M$
$(b)$ $M$ is a pushout $\bigcup^{M, \mathcal{D}}_{\alpha \in \Lambda} U_{\alpha}$ of all $U_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in \Lambda$ w.r.t. to $M$ and is defined inductively (which works, up to isomorphism, due to the associativity of the pullbacks and the pushouts (this part is non-trivial I admit, but from the literature I've come across it can be reasonably assumed or in the worst case, added in the definition of a geometric pair of categories)) such that for $\alpha, \beta \in \Lambda$, $\hspace{5mm} \bigcup^{M, \mathcal{D}}_{\gamma \in \{ \alpha, \beta \}} U_{\gamma} := U_{\alpha} \cup_{M, \mathcal{D}} U_{\beta}$ and for $I$ a finite subset of $Λ$ and $\alpha \in Λ \setminus I$, $\hspace{5mm} \bigcup^{M, \mathcal{D}}_{\gamma \in I \cup \{ \alpha \}} U_{\gamma} := \bigcup^{M, \mathcal{D}}_{\gamma \in I} U_{\gamma} \cup_{M, \mathcal{D}} U_{\alpha}$
$(c)$ For $(U_{\alpha}, \varphi_{\alpha}), (U_{\beta}, \varphi_{\beta})$ two ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical parameterizations of $M$ in $\mathcal{A}$, if the pullback $U_{\alpha} \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\beta}$ is not an initial object of $\mathcal{D}$, then there exists $V'_{\alpha}$ and $V'_{\beta}$ objects of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $V'_{\alpha} \subset_{\mathcal{C}} V_{\alpha}$ and $V'_{\beta} \subset_{\mathcal{C}} V_{\beta}$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\alpha}$ to $U_{\alpha} \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\beta}$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and $\varphi_{\beta}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\beta}$ to $U_{\alpha} \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\beta}$ in $\mathcal{D}$ (with $V_{\alpha}$ resp. $V_{\beta}$ from the definitions of $(U_{\alpha}, \varphi_{\alpha})$ resp. $(U_{\beta}, \varphi_{\beta})$), and we have that $\varphi_{\beta}^{-1} \circ \varphi_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\alpha}$ to $V'_{\beta}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1} \circ \varphi_{\beta}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\beta}$ to $V'_{\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{C}$
Finally, for ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) a geometric pair of categories, let ($M$, $\mathcal{A}$) be a ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical manifold if $M$ is an object of $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{A}$ is a ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical atlas of $M$ and
$(d)$ (Maximality of $\mathcal{A}$ as an atlas of $M$) For $(U, \varphi)$ a ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical parameterization of $M$, if for all $(U_{\alpha}, \varphi_{\alpha})$ ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$)-categorical parameterizations of $M$ such that if the pullback $U \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\alpha}$ is not an initial object of $\mathcal{D}$ then there exists $V'$ and $V'_{\alpha}$ objects of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $V' \subset_{\mathcal{C}} V$ and $V'_{\alpha} \subset_{\mathcal{C}} V_{\alpha}$ (with $V$ resp. $V_{\alpha}$ from the definitions of $(U, \varphi)$ resp. $(U_{\alpha}, \varphi_{\alpha})$) and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism from $V'$ to $U \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\alpha}$ to $U \cap_{X, \mathcal{D}} U_{\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1} \circ \varphi$ is an isomorphism from $V'$ to $V'_{\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and $\varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism from $V'_{\alpha}$ to $V'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $(U, \varphi) \in \mathcal{A}$
Also, another definition of interest (for all the interest such a theory is worth anyway) might be the following :
For ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) a geometric pair of categories, ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) is said to be (geometrically) trivial if the following conditions are met :
$(i)$ (Absorption of $\mathcal{D}$ by $\mathcal{C}$) For $X$ an object of $\mathcal{D}$ and $Y$ an object of $\mathcal{C}$, if they are isomorphic in $\mathcal{D}$ (i.e. there exists an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ in $\mathcal{D}$), then $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$
$(ii)$ (Stability by countable union) For $X$ an object of $\mathcal{D}$, if $X$ is a pushout $\bigcup^{X, \mathcal{D}}_{\alpha \in \Lambda} Y_{\alpha}$ of all $Y_{\alpha}$ (defined inductively the same way as in the section $(b)$ of the definition of the atlas) of a countable collection of objects of $\mathcal{C} \hspace{2mm}$ $\{Y_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$, and such that for all $\alpha \in Λ$, $Y_{\alpha} \subset_{\mathcal{D}} X$, then $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$
It is easy to see that every categorical manifold $M$ w.r.t. a trivial geometric pair of categories ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) is an object of $\mathcal{C}$, thus "trivialising" the manifolds hence the name.

So that brings my question : Has this been significantly researched yet ?
I tried for instance, to get a feel of (Field, Ring)-categorical manifolds are like, and it turns out that (Field, Ring) is a geometrically trivial pair of categories as defined above, and actually the same seems to apply for every geometrical pair ($\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$) with $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ being subcategories of Magma, and defined using "well-behaved" first-order properties (maybe some sort of generalized Markov property for magmas instead of finitely generated groups I suppose,) but I haven't investigated that thoroughly yet.
Maybe it's too "infertile" to be studied as is if we don't add stronger hypotheses to such manifolds $M$ and the categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ (I mean that could partly explain why schemes in algebraic geometry have been so fruitful for example.) Maybe that whole thing is ill-defined to begin with, and no significant attempts have been made to make it well-defined, mainly due to a lack of motivation. Nonetheless, I feel like such a theory could have great applications to other fields if developed properly (that probably sounds pretty obvious to most people reading this since the theory is very general to begin with, but I say it anyway to make an emphasis on it.)
Thanks in advance
Edit: I have reworked the whole post massively so as to make this theory workable since the previous version was ill-defined in many ways (the definition for the atlas for instance had its formalism mixed up between charts and parameterizations which may have made it very confusing at best, I admit.) To be honest, I made the edit more for closure than anything, and also to share that with other people who might come up with interesting developments regarding such "categorical manifolds".

Your definition of $\subseteq_{\mathcal{D}}$ doesn't parse: $\mathrm{Id}{|Y|}|{|X|}$ is a morphism in $\mathrm{Set}$, not in $\mathcal{C}$, so it can't be in $\mathcal{C}_{\ll}(X, Y)$. Moreover there is no reason to suppose that there exists a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ covering it (there need be no morphism $X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ at all), so it's unclear what you mean. Certainly you don't want this to just be a mono in $\mathrm{Set}$, because then the condition is trivial.

The best I can think of is that you want there to be a monic $X \to Y$ covering the inclusion $|X| \subseteq |Y|$. If this is what you want, then I suggest the following: If $|{{-}}|$ preserves pullbacks (which is often the case), then it preserves monics, so you might as well say that $A \subseteq_{\mathcal{D}} B$ if there exist a monic $A \to B$ (if you're willing to identify monics with inclusions). Your notion of $A \cap_{X,, \mathcal{D}} B$ becomes "pullback of $A \to X \leftarrow B$; this leaves you off which  cleaner foundations that what you have.

Even with goodwill I cannot parse your definition of categorical atlas, however: The composites $\phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$ simply aren't defined. $\phi_\alpha, \phi_beta$ are isomorphisms from some objects $V_\alpha, V_\beta \in \mathcal{C}$ to $U_\alpha, U_\beta$, respectively, and there's no reason to suppose $V_\alpha$ is in any way related to $V_\beta$. You also generally assume that the existence of morphisms on the set level, after applying the forgetful functor, somehow translates to the existence of morphisms in the overlying category. This is false.

As it is right now, I don't think this question is workable, and I'll have to vote to close. If you want us to tell you whether this theory is studied, you should go back to the drawing board and clean it up to the point it is error-free and understandable. Some closing remarks: You seem to assume that every category has a forgetful functor to $\mathrm{Set}$. This is false, and if a category does, it's never unique. Your theory right now is extremely sensitive to the choice of forgetful functor; that should be a warning sign. Also, we generally prefer words over symbols :)

Wow I was expecting some points to be ill-defined, but I didn't think it was to this extent. Sorry for wasting your time I guess. Anyway I'll work on it to make it as sound as you suggest.

I don't think that this is a good approach to generalize manifolds. Apart from the things already mentioned in the comments, you put too much emphasis on the forgetful functor to the category of sets. But most importantly, your abstraction is not based on examples or applications. You have tried to generalize what is happening in the case of manifolds, but this alone is not sufficient to develop a good abstraction. In fact, you could not find any other interesting example of your theory. This is a bad sign. Research in mathematics (usually) goes the other way round. You need at least two examples in mind for which you want to find a link between them.
On a personal note, let me mention that I have also done this a lot when I was younger, that is, building abstractions without having examples and applications in mind from the start. I tried to generalize scheme theory to an absurd degree, developed a theory quite similar to Hakim's Topos anneles et schemas relatifs by accident, without having any proper motiviation and examples in mind. I regret doing this.
As for your question, you might want to check out Zhen Lin's thesis:

Zhen Lin, Categories of spaces built from local models, University of Cambridge, 2016

There are also other approaches to generalize manifolds in a categorical setup. See for example:

Juan A. Navarro González & Juan B. Sancho de Salas, C∞-Differentiable Spaces, LNM 1824


Thank you for the reference. Also yes, I was worried that this abstraction was not a good approach since I hadn't managed to find any literature on it. But I'd like to see that idea through anyway for the sake of it even though that may be unfruitful, maybe by making it less dependant on the choice of forgetful functors as has been mentioned in the other comments.
Regardless, thanks for the feedback.

Actually, I think it would be best to close this question, since not only the theory as I formalised it (for what is salvageable) is not "mature" enough for it to be interesting, and you provided references for me to work with. I'll accept this answer and play around with the idea by myself just to seek closure I suppose, but yes the theory itself probably won't amount to much if we're being honest.
